# mysql login after install [ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mike'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]

Tags: mysql, authentication, installation

Using a mac w/ mountain lion, I just installed mysql.  I am now trying to login using the following command

```
mysql -u mike -p
```

but get the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'mike'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have referenced the following SO question & answer: [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

based on all those answers I need to create a new local user inside mysql command line, but how do I do this if I can't get access to the `mysql>` (command line)?

Comment: Have you tried using the root account and then creating the user `bill`?

Comment: mysql -u mike -pmypassword outputs the same?

Comment: @Triztian I used root and got in, do I need to create a user 'mike@localhost' or will 'mike' work?

Comment: You have to create the `mike` user. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `root` user has no password in MySQL (unless you set a root password in mysql during the install). Try logging in like this:

```
mysql -u root
```

Note the exclusion of the `-p` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$ mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'mike'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'secret';";
```

And then see [Grant Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) for setting the appropriate priviledges.